# python, adding break in function or process only once

Tags: python, function, loops

i have text files which contains file extension .java, .c and .cpp.
script.py is working but how can add a break in a function? 
If script is processing test1.txt, I would like it to go to action1 and action2 only once for that particular file.

test.txt

```
abc/sas/.java
```

test1.txt

```
abc/sas/.java
abc/asfa/.java
def/def/.c
e/e/.cpp
e/fa/.cpp
```

script.py

```
PWD1 = PWD + "/folder"
set = ""
files = glob.glob(PWD1 + '/' + '*.txt')
def action1():
    print("ACTION1")

def action2():
    print("ACTION2")

strings = {'.java': action1, '.c' or '.cpp': action2}
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        for line in sorted(file):
            print(line)
            for search, action in strings.items():
                if search in line:
                    action()
```

Comment: `{'.c' or '.cpp': action2}` isn't doing what you think.

Comment: you need to do action 1 and action 2 only once, for a given txt?

Comment: what you mean, please explain? when i run the script, it is processing as excepted.

Comment: @hsnsd - that is correct and same for any numbers of file under "folder".

Comment: `'.c' or '.cpp'` will always evaluate to `'.c'`, so that dictionary will never have a key of `'.cpp'`.

Comment: how many actions and which do you need for your tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of actions being performed, so that you only perform action1 once, and action2 once, and then break out.

If I understand correctly, the below code should work.

```
for f in files:
    a1 = False
    a2 = False
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        for line in sorted(file):
            if a1 is False and '.java' in line:
                action1()
                a1 = True
            elif a2 is False and ('.cpp' in line or '.c' in line):
                action2()
                a2 = True
            if a1 and a2:
                break
```

Comment: thank you for prompt reply but script only works for one text file.. issue seen when second text file was added

Comment: @Mihir dint test it with two files. Whats the issue?

Comment: output was (ACTION1,ACTION2,ACTION1,ACTION2). second text file has only .java line. for some reason it added ACTION2.

Comment: thank you once again for helping but it didn't work this time either.. output results: ACTION1, ACTIONS2... desired output: ACTION1, ACTIONS2,ACTION1

Comment: @Mihir missed resetting the booleans. Now it should work

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, to answer your question, you can do the following:

```
ext_to_actions = {'java': action1, 'c': action2, 'cpp': action2}
for f in files:
    performed_actions = set()
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        for line in sorted(file):
            print(line)
            file_ext = line.split('.')[-1]
            if file_ext in ext_to_actions:
                action = ext_to_actions[file_ext]
                if action not in performed_actions:
                    action()
                    performed_actions.add(action)
```

What this does is remove the ability for the action to be taken more than once by tracking executed actions in a `set` and keeping you from repeating actions.

Second, your dictionary is not going to behave like you expect.

```
>>> strings = {'.java': action1, '.c' or '.cpp': action2}
>>> strings
{'.java': action1, '.c': action2}
```

This is because when you are creating the `strings` dictionary you are actually asking python to programmatically select between `'.c' or '.cpp'`.  See the following code snippet to see how python interprets this:

```
>>> '.c' or '.cpp'
'.c'
```

What you want is the following...

```
strings = {'.java': action1, '.cpp': action2, '.c': action2}
```

Comment: thank you for great explanation, following didn't work for multiple text files. I will try your latest updated code.  "if action and line.endswith(search):
action()
strings[search] = None"

Comment: yeah, sorry i put some typos in there at first (and had a bad first solution, as i didn't understand the problem you were trying to solve).  should be good with the latest edit

Comment: ahh, just move the performed actions set down a line then.  i'll edit the code to show what i mean

Comment: let me know if that doesn't work.  i was thinking you meant once per action per run, not once per action per file

Comment: Thank you very much @Julian for helping and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfold the inner loop and add the break statement at very end? Or use flags. Remove `"or '.cpp'"`, `or` should not be used in dictionaries like that. basically `'.c' or '.cpp'` evaluates to `".c"`, yet bad style. Probably you meant 'endswith' rather than in?